# What is the age of goddess adiparashakti?

Tags: goddess

What is the age of goddess Adiparashakti and stories related to her in details with goddesses Saraswati's, Lakshmi's, and Parvati Mata's full lifetimes?

Comment: Both gods and goddesses are immortal and so are ageless. One might say they are as old as the universe but that is being merely scientofic rather than going by scripture.

Comment: The question requests an answer so large in scope, I'm not sure it will ever be answered. Consider fine-tuning the question.